# Will a C# book written for VS2013 be too confusing to follow if I use VS2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have a quick question. I'm about to start with the book "Head First C#", the latest edition. It focuses on development on Windows 8.1 in combination with Visual Studio 2013. However, I'm running Windows 10. Can I use Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 or does it differ to much from Visual Studio 2013 that I won't be able to follow the book properly. Thank you in advance for the information!

Comment: most of the things in the book will still apply. There are improvements in VS2015 so I would switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2015 supports everything that VS2013 does and in addition has some new features. So it will not be confusing for you tofollow the book even if it is written for VS2013. Also the if the book is for the C# language, the Visual Studio version really doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's much appreciated.